# Table CSS left border Issue with CSS Code

Tags: css

Far Left borders shows nothing in entire table. how do I fix it in below CSS code ? Border is now showing any of the color all other cells are good.

Below is my existing CSS Code. Thanks in Advance.

```css
#mytable {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
caption {
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  width: 700px;
  font: italic 11px"Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
}
th {
  font: bold 11px"Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #4f6b72;
  border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  border-top: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
  background: #CAE8EA url(/images/bg_header.jpg) no-repeat;
}
th.nobg {
  border-top: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  background: none;
}
td {
  border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
  color: #4f6b72;
}
td.alt {
  background: #F5FAFA;
  color: #797268;
}
th.spec {
  border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  border-top: 0;
  background: #fff url(/images/bullet1.gif) no-repeat;
  font: bold 10px"Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
th.specalt {
  border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  border-top: 0;
  background: #f5fafa url(/images/bullet2.gif) no-repeat;
  font: bold 10px"Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #797268;
}
/* Below CSS is used for jQuery Popup window used for File Upload*/

#fade {
  /*--Transparent background layer--*/
  display: none;
  /*--hidden by default--*/
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .80;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.popup_block {
  display: none;
  /*--hidden by default--*/
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 20px solid #ddd;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 99999;
  /*--CSS3 Box Shadows--*/
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
  /*--CSS3 Rounded Corners--*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
img.btn_close {
  float: right;
  margin: -55px -55px 0 0;
}
/*--Making IE6 Understand Fixed Positioning--*/

*html #fade {
  position: absolute;
}
*html .popup_block {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>TEST</tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TEST</td>
    <td>TEST</td>
    <td>TEST
    <td>TEST</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you add some HTML to the snippet?

Comment: please see below: <table id="mytable">
<tr>
TEST
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
TEST</td>
<td>
TEST</td>
<td>
TEST
<td>
TEST
</td>
</tr>
</table>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right you want the same border in left `td`. You can use this:

```
td:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
}
```

```css
#mytable {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
caption {
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  width: 700px;
  font: italic 11px"Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
}
th {
  font: bold 11px"Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #4f6b72;
  border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  border-top: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
  background: #CAE8EA url(/images/bg_header.jpg) no-repeat;
}
th.nobg {
  border-top: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  background: none;
}
td {
  border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
  color: #4f6b72;
}
td.alt {
  background: #F5FAFA;
  color: #797268;
}
th.spec {
  border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  border-top: 0;
  background: #fff url(/images/bullet1.gif) no-repeat;
  font: bold 10px"Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
th.specalt {
  border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  border-top: 0;
  background: #f5fafa url(/images/bullet2.gif) no-repeat;
  font: bold 10px"Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #797268;
}
/* Below CSS is used for jQuery Popup window used for File Upload*/

#fade {
  /*--Transparent background layer--*/
  display: none;
  /*--hidden by default--*/
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .80;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.popup_block {
  display: none;
  /*--hidden by default--*/
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 20px solid #ddd;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 99999;
  /*--CSS3 Box Shadows--*/
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
  /*--CSS3 Rounded Corners--*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
img.btn_close {
  float: right;
  margin: -55px -55px 0 0;
}
/*--Making IE6 Understand Fixed Positioning--*/

*html #fade {
  position: absolute;
}
*html .popup_block {
  position: absolute;
}
td:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>TEST</tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TEST</td>
    <td>TEST</td>
    <td>TEST
      <td>TEST</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could just add `border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7;` to your `td` definition and maybe change `border-collapse: separate;` to `border-collapse: collapse;` in `#mytable`.

It's also possible to add left `border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7;` on entire table in `#mytable`.

Answer (score 0):

The common solution is to either use `:first-child` or the adjacent operator: `+` but these are not supported in IE6. You may need to handle that browser separately for these styles if this is a requirement. (Use conditional comments, maybe?)

Anyway, I've tried to pull out the relevant CSS and assumed some things about the markup to come up with this:

```css
#mytable {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
}
td + td, th + th {
    border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
}
tr + tr {
    border-top: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
}

td {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
    color: #4f6b72;
}

th {
    font: bold 11px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #4f6b72;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
    background: #CAE8EA url(/images/bg_header.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <th>TEST1</th>
        <th>TEST2</th>
        <th>TEST3</th>
        <th>TEST4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>TEST1</td>
        <td>TEST2</td>
        <td>TEST3</td>
        <td>TEST4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```